# Is this set "trivially" bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, compactness

I have to show that the set $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}=\left\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|\mathbf{x}\|_2=1\right\}$ is compact in $\left(\mathbb{R^{n}},\|\cdot\|_2\right)$. I have shown that the set is closed, but now I must show that it is bounded.

I said for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, $\|\mathbf{x}\|_2=1$, so we have that $\|\mathbf{x}\|_2\leq1$. So by definition, $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is bounded.

Is this okay to say? I haven't really had to show that a set was bounded before, and I felt like this was too simple, so I am second-guessing myself if it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very trivially bounded. You've shown it is contained in the closed ball of radius $1$.